# .NET Change Temp Path

Tags: .net, azure, file, temp

How to set temp path for this two methods?

```
System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()
System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()
```

My company application was designed for Windows 2008 with .NET 4.0. However the application is going to support both Windows 2008 and Azure.

Since Azure does not allow local file writes, no temp file can be created in Azure. In the application, there are many places using temp file for massive works (that means we cannot put the data in memory since the temp file is huge.)

My plan is going to create a `TempFileWrapper` to replace the original temp file generation. However, if there is simply way to change the return values from `System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()` and `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath`, that saves my works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Blatantly copied from this [blog post](http://abdullin.squarespace.com/journal/2010/11/29/windows-azure-sqlite-and-temp.html), 3rd google hit:

```
var tempPath = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("Temp").RootPath;
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP", tempPath);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TMP", tempPath);
```

Answer (score 5):

The [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettemppath) describes how `GetTempPath` finds the path:

1. The path specified by the `TMP` environment variable.
2. The path specified by the `TEMP` environment variable.
3. The path specified by the `USERPROFILE` environment variable.
4. The Windows directory.

So simply change the `TMP` or `TEMP` environment variable.

Comment: Could we change these variable in Azure?

Comment: Yes, you can. Looks like Hans Passant beat me to it, though.